# Why does the mirror modifier not mirror perfectly?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

I have added a mirror modifier then the skin modifier to my mesh.

I get this:

[image: problem]

But I'm supposed to have this:

[image: No problem]

What I did I do wrong ?

Comment: are you sure you added the right screenshots? I mean both show the object before any modifier has been applied. I can't tell the difference.

Comment: @stacker the mirror and skin modifiers have been used but the two screenshots do look identical to me, just from different angles.  I think by “applied” he means used, not actually *applied*.

Comment: @PGmath Sorry you're right, when I say "applied" I want to say used.

Comment: @stacker when you put "mirror" in the first one is supposed to get the 2nd picture but my shape does not change.

Comment: The pictures appear to differ in the concave/convex respect of the beam that runs the center of the object

Answer (score 4):

Your vertices are not at the exact center.

[image]

change their position to 0 on the concerned axis
[image]
This should fix your problem
[image]

This could be avoided using clipping in the mirror modifier.